# DocuSign Unauthorized error on createEnvelope

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to use Docusign to sign from my NodeJS app. After creating a token, as next step, I am trying to create Envelope (Step 1 of https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/signing-from-your-app )

I used [createEnvelope(accountId, opts, callback)](http://docusign.github.io/docusign-node-client/module-api_EnvelopesApi.html#createEnvelope) method from REST API passing the account ID and EnvelopeDefinition. But, it return Unauthorized 401 error ("errorCode": "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",\r\n  "message": "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified). I have not passed the Integrator key but I am confused where to pass the key.

Comment: Can you please share your complete code of how you are calling DS APIs. You need to pass your AccessToken in the Header of the request

Comment: I tried to replicate code from https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/signing-from-your-app 



var envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi();
envelopesApi.createEnvelope(accountId, {'envelopeDefinition': envDef}, function (err, envelopeSummary, response) {
if (err) {
  return next(err);
}
console.log('EnvelopeSummary: ' + JSON.stringify(envelopeSummary));

Comment: You need to generate the AccessToken, check code [github](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-code-examples/blob/master/node/NodeSDKSamples.js) for more details and example uses `DocuSign OAuth Authorization Code Grant flow`

Comment: Yesh, I generated the access token. I know it needs to be sent in header. I would like to know how to use API methods ( http://docusign.github.io/docusign-node-client/module-api_EnvelopesApi.html ) to get this done.

Comment: Try checking the github code which I added in my last comment, it has description of how to use that code for different DS functionalities.